# Oracle DEFAULT clause for create table. "Literal argument"?

Tags: sql, oracle, default

I was just reading the documentation for the CREATE TABLE statement and it says this in relation to the DEFAULT clause:

> "The DEFAULT expression can include any SQL function as long as the
>   function does not return a literal argument, a column reference, or a
>   nested function invocation."
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm

What does it mean by the function cannot return a "literal argument". I thought returning literals was OK for DEFAULT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to use literals with DEFAULT, for example DEFAULT 'YES' . What is telling you that text is that if you are using a function in DEFAULT, for example `DEFAULT POWER(2,3)` , that function POWER must not return a literal argument. You can use [SQL built in functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm)  in the clause DEFAULT  , but not USER defined PLSQL functions

Comment: I think part of the question is, what is a "literal argument"?  Can you give an example of the kind of built-in SQL function that would not work as a default?

Comment: SCORE, REF, AREF , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH are some examples of functions that wouldn't work in DEFAULT , because they are in the category of functions that return "literal argument, a column reference, or a nested function invocation"

Comment: It makes sense to me why those functions wouldn't work, but I'm still confused about what "literal argument" means.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main thing that I don't understand. What is the difference between a literal and a "literal argument"? Are they the same thing in this context?